# Postgres, TimescaleDB Setup: Unsure how to make all relevant binaries are in your PATH: pg_config

Tags: windows, postgresql, configuration, timescaledb

I'm setting up TimescaleDB, on a Windows 10 machine.
https://docs.timescale.com/v0.9/getting-started/installation/windows/installation-windows
It says a prerequisite is to:
Make sure all relevant binaries are in your PATH: pg_config

I am not exactly sure what this even means. Is this telling me to put the path to my pg10\bin in the system variables PATH? If this is the case, why do they say "pg_config"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would have been better to say “... are *on* your PATH”.

Anyway, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I opened up another question because I cannot get TimescaleDB working on my machine still. I was hoping you could take a peak to see if you know what I can do to run TimescaleDB on my machine. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562434/cannot-succesfully-install-timescaledb-on-postgres-10-windows-server-2016