# Cannot succesfully install TimescaleDB on Postgres 10 (Windows Server 2016)

Tags: database, postgresql, timescaledb

I am having trouble getting TimescaleDB to work on my windows server 2016 machine with Postgres 10.

1. I open up a fresh windows server 2016 instance with AWS and I install Postgres using the windows GUI installer. (C:\Postgres).
2. The installer automatically updates the path to include the bin directory (C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin).
3. I stop postgres.
4. I run the TimescaleDB windows installer file and it says it's successfully completed.
5. I update the conf file. (shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb').
6. I restart my computer and start postgres, but postgres never sucessfully starts.  The windows event yells at me, saying I   2018-03-29 17:01:35 UTC [952]: [1-1] user=,db=,app=,client= FATAL: could not load library "C:/POSTGR~1/pg10/../pg10/lib/postgresql/timescaledb.dll": The specified module could not be found.

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Does the file exist? Does it depend on other DLLs that are not on the PATH (use tools suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7378959/6464308) to find out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be related to https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/485#issuecomment-377533298 which is caused by a missing dependency, Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.